# Is there a way to parse out column names instead of defining them?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, jdbc

Using `Java/Selenium/Excel` sheets I have an automation script. When verifying information in the database, I am doing something like this:

```
//Get values from Excel.  Excel user will specify what table and what user
String table=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, "table",currentTestDataSetID);
String user=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, "user",currentTestDataSetID);

//Run query
 PreparedStatement pstmt1 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + table +" WHERE User = '" + user + "' ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1;"); 


if(table.equals("A")){ 
        rs1.next();
                //Get results from A table
                String db_TableAColumn1=rs1.getString("TableAColumn1");
                String db_TableAColumn2=rs1.getString("TableAColumn2");
                String db_TableAColumn3=rs1.getString("TableAColumn3");
                //Get values from excel
                String excel_TableAColumn1=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, "TableAColumn1",currentTestDataSetID);  
                String excel_TableAColumn2=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, "TableAColumn2",currentTestDataSetID);  
                String excel_TableAColumn3=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, "TableAColumn3",currentTestDataSetID);  

                    if(db_TableAColumn1.equals(excel_TableAColumnA)) { ...
                    if(db_TableAColumn2.equals(excel_TableAColumn2)) { ... 
                    if(db_TableAColumn3.equals(excel_TableAColumn3)) { ...


if(table.equals("B")){ 
        rs1.next();
                //Get results from B table
                String db_TableBColumn1=rs1.getString("TableBColumn1");
                String db_TableBColumn2=rs1.getString("TableBColumn2");
                String db_TableBColumn3=rs1.getString("TableBColumn3");
                //Get values from excel
                String excel_TableBColumn1=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, "TableBColumn1",currentTestDataSetID);  
                String excel_TableBColumn2=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, "TableBColumn2",currentTestDataSetID);  
                String excel_TableBColumn3=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, "TableBColumn3",currentTestDataSetID);  

                    if(db_TableBColumn1.equals(excel_TableBColumn1)) { ...
                    if(db_TableBColumn2.equals(excel_TableBColumn2)) { ... 
                    if(db_TableBColumn3.equals(excel_TableBColumn3)) { ...
```

So this is currently working fine.  However, it is not very scalable.

- If  we want to start to check a new column on the A table (or if a new column is added) we need to update the java code.  We only want to modify the excel sheet.  Is there  a way to parse all the columns from the result set, and if a column is in the excel sheet then we check to see if it exists in the result set, if so, then check to see if the expected values match up?

**Is there a way to do For each column in the table**

String GiveAName= rs1.getString(1); until all columns are given a name

Then if each column in specified in excel has a value, match up.

**Instead of defining everything like:**

```
String db_TableAColumn1=rs1.getString("TableAColumn1");
```

or

```
String db_TableAColumn1= rs1.getString(1);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ResultSetMetaData` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html,

It will allow you to dynamically retrieve column names of a table.

example:

```
      ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
      int columns = md.getColumnCount();
      while (rs.next()){
         for(int i=1; i<=columns; ++i){           
             System.out.println("Column name: " + md.getColumnName(i) + " Col Value: " +rs.getObject(i));
         }
      }
```

Comment: Cool, thank you.  One concern while compiling.  I have `ResultSet rs1 = pstmt1.executeQuery();` and when I just add the line `ResultSetMetaData md = rs1.getMetaData();` I get a compile error, cannot find symbol

Comment: You need to import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData